# format numbers with variable length

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have a bunch of numbers in a list and want to print them in a pretty way, so that they are aligned on the right side.

```
numbers = [192829, 88288, 912, 1992, 2828, 38]
for number in numbers:
    print("{:6d}".format(number))
```

This gives me:

```
192829
 88288
   912
  1992
  2828
    38
```

This works, because I knew that longest number is 6 digits long, so I hardcoded 6: `"{:6d}"`

What if I don't know the longest number. The only solution I can think of, is the following.

```
length = len(str(max(numbers)))
output_template = "{:" + str(length) + "d}"
for number in numbers:
    print(output_template.format(number))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: better way? Its a good way actually, none of other ways can be better than _max_ function.

Comment: Unless you can predict the maximum number, there is no way to do better than max.

Comment: As long as your numbers aren't going to be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a variable into `str.format`, you don't need to create a template:

```
numbers = [192829, 88288, 912, 1992, 2828, 38]
for number in numbers:
    print("{0:{1}d}".format(number,len(str(max(numbers)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> len(str(max(numbers))

gives you the length of the biggest number, so you can use this

Answer (score 0):

this you can try:

```
>>> numbers = [192829, 88288, 912, 1992, 2828, 38]
>>> length = len(str(max(numbers)))    # max give you larget number and len find its length
>>> for x in numbers:
...     print("{:{}d}".format(x,length))
... 
192829
 88288
   912
  1992
  2828
    38
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is another way;

```
numbers = [192829, 88288, 912, 1992, 2828, 38,4536,3564576,2342342]
maxlen=len(max(str(numbers),key=len))
print (("{:^{dif}}\n"*len(numbers)).format(*numbers,dif=maxlen))
```

Comment: there is no need to use key=length, as the number who will be max, its obvious that has max number of digits